# numpy.ndarray lambda is not callable within loop when using scipy.minimize_scalar, works fine single-run

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm working on a piece of code that calculates surface wave velocities. When I run this as a single-shot in my Jupyter notebook it works fine, however when I try to start looping over the phi1 angle, I end up with the 'numpy.ndarray is not callable error' after the zero iteration of the loop.

It seems to be focused on the lambda (`g`) I am using, but I am not sure the best way to go about debugging it. Any help/review would be greatly appreciated as Google searches aren't helping too much.

I do apologize for the novel of code, but this is trimmed down to where it should be easily reproducible.

```
## This code is an implementation of the framework described by M. Cherry et al. in
## Cherry, Matthew R., Shamachary Sathish, and Ramana Grandhi. "A numerical method for predicting Rayleigh surface wave
## velocity in anisotropic crystals." Journal of Computational Physics 351 (2017): 108-120.
## The logic of this code is as follows.
##    (1) It then calculates R, T, and Qv (which is the velocity independent Q, needed to determine the velocity range
##    over which to search.
##    (2)  It then iterates to determine the velocity range by changing a variable called 'angle'.
##    (3)  It then finds a minimum vL, and solves for Q (with velocity as a term), N, A, B, and Z matrices.
##    (4)  It stores the three Euler angles (p1, P, p2) and RSW_vel
##    This does not deal with pseudowaves yet.

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.optimize as spo
import scipy.linalg as la
from scipy.linalg import eig, eigvals
import math
from decimal import *
import time

ts1 = time.time()
# Setup material properties
# Setup the Cij matrix of Ni (units in Pa)
C11 = C22 = C33 = 2.41e11
C12 = C13 = C23 = C21 = C31 = C32 = 1.47e11
C14 = C15 = C16 = C24 = C25 = C26 = C34 = C35 = C36 = C41 = C42 = C43 = C51 = C52 = C53 = C61 = C62 = C63 = 0
C44 = C55 = C66 = 1.26e11
C45 = C46 = C56 = C54 = C64 = C65 = 0
Cij_list = np.array([C11,C12,C13,C14,C15,C16,C21,C22,C23,C24,C25,C26,C31,C32,C33,C34,C35,C36,C41,C42,C43,C44,C45,C46,C51,C52,C53,C54,C55,C56,C61,C62,C63,C64,C65,C66])
Cij=Cij_list.reshape(6,6)
print('Cij =')
print(Cij)
# Setup density of Ni (units are in kg/m3)
rho = 8910
RSW_matrix = np.array([0,0,0,0])

## This is where the setting up of the loop for p1, P, and p2 should be.
# Setup Euler Angles in Bunge's active notation (one time only - demo, will need to be iterated over), angles in degrees. p1 = phi1, P = Phi, p2 = phi2
#p1 = 15
P = 45
p2 = 8

for rotation in range(0, 180):
    ## Below this point, everything must be done for every Euler calculation.
    p1_rad = np.radians(rotation)
    P_rad = np.radians(P)
    p2_rad = np.radians(p2)
    Eul_Ang_deg = np.array([p1,P,p2])
    Eul_Ang_rad = np.array([p1_rad,P_rad,p2_rad])
    c1 = np.cos(p1_rad)
    c2 = np.cos(P_rad)
    c3 = np.cos(p2_rad)
    s1 = np.sin(p1_rad)
    s2 = np.sin(P_rad)
    s3 = np.sin(p2_rad)

    # Solve Rotation Matrix from Bunge's active notation, and m and n (m is wave propagation vector, n is plane normal)
    Rot_mat = np.array([[c1*c3-c2*s1*s3,-c1*s3-c2*c3*s1,s1*s2],
                        [c3*s1+c1*c2*s3,c1*c2*c3-s1*s3,-c1*s2],
                        [s2*s3,c3*s2,c2]])    #- could fill in the rest here and just extract col 1 and col 3

    print('Rotation Matrix =')
    print(Rot_mat)

    m_vec = Rot_mat[[0],:]
    m1 = Rot_mat[[0],[0]]
    m2 = Rot_mat[[0],[1]]
    m3 = Rot_mat[[0],[2]]
    n_vec = Rot_mat[[2],:]
    n1 = Rot_mat[[2],[0]]
    n2 = Rot_mat[[2],[1]]
    n3 = Rot_mat[[2],[2]]


    # Below, we calculate R, T and Q matrices
    # CORRECT R matrix calculations
    Rij = np.ndarray(shape=(3,3))
    Rij[0,0] = C11*m1*n1 + C61*m2*n1 + C51*m3*n1 + C16*m1*n2 + C66*m2*n2 + C56*m3*n2 + C15*m1*n3 + C65*m2*n3 + C55*m3*n3
    Rij[0,1] = C16*m1*n1 + C66*m2*n1 + C56*m3*n1 + C12*m1*n2 + C62*m2*n2 + C52*m3*n2 + C14*m1*n3 + C64*m2*n3 + C54*m3*n3
    Rij[0,2] = C15*m1*n1 + C65*m2*n1 + C55*m3*n1 + C14*m1*n2 + C64*m2*n2 + C54*m3*n2 + C13*m1*n3 + C63*m2*n3 + C53*m3*n3
    Rij[1,0] = C61*m1*n1 + C21*m2*n1 + C41*m3*n1 + C66*m1*n2 + C26*m2*n2 + C46*m3*n2 + C65*m1*n3 + C25*m2*n3 + C45*m3*n3
    Rij[1,1] = C66*m1*n1 + C26*m2*n1 + C46*m3*n1 + C62*m1*n2 + C22*m2*n2 + C42*m3*n2 + C64*m1*n3 + C24*m2*n3 + C44*m3*n3
    Rij[1,2] = C65*m1*n1 + C25*m2*n1 + C45*m3*n1 + C64*m1*n2 + C24*m2*n2 + C44*m3*n2 + C63*m1*n3 + C23*m2*n3 + C43*m3*n3
    Rij[2,0] = C51*m1*n1 + C41*m2*n1 + C31*m3*n1 + C56*m1*n2 + C46*m2*n2 + C36*m3*n2 + C55*m1*n3 + C45*m2*n3 + C35*m3*n3
    Rij[2,1] = C56*m1*n1 + C46*m2*n1 + C36*m3*n1 + C52*m1*n2 + C42*m2*n2 + C32*m3*n2 + C54*m1*n3 + C44*m2*n3 + C34*m3*n3
    Rij[2,2] = C55*m1*n1 + C45*m2*n1 + C35*m3*n1 + C54*m1*n2 + C44*m2*n2 + C34*m3*n2 + C53*m1*n3 + C43*m2*n3 + C33*m3*n3
    Rij_trans = np.transpose(Rij)
    Rij_inv = np.linalg.inv(Rij)

    # CORRECT T matrix calculations
    Tij = np.ndarray(shape=(3,3))
    Tij[0,0] = C11*n1*n1 + C16*n2*n1 + C51*n3*n1 + C16*n1*n2 + C66*n2*n2 + C56*n3*n2 + C15*n1*n3 + C65*n2*n3 + C55*n3*n3
    Tij[0,1] = C16*n1*n1 + C66*n2*n1 + C56*n3*n1 + C12*n1*n2 + C62*n2*n2 + C52*n3*n2 + C14*n1*n3 + C64*n2*n3 + C54*n3*n3
    Tij[0,2] = C15*n1*n1 + C65*n2*n1 + C55*n3*n1 + C14*n1*n2 + C64*n2*n2 + C54*n3*n2 + C13*n1*n3 + C63*n2*n3 + C53*n3*n3
    Tij[1,0] = C61*n1*n1 + C21*n2*n1 + C41*n3*n1 + C66*n1*n2 + C26*n2*n2 + C46*n3*n2 + C65*n1*n3 + C25*n2*n3 + C45*n3*n3
    Tij[1,1] = C66*n1*n1 + C26*n2*n1 + C46*n3*n1 + C62*n1*n2 + C22*n2*n2 + C42*n3*n2 + C64*n1*n3 + C24*n2*n3 + C44*n3*n3
    Tij[1,2] = C65*n1*n1 + C25*n2*n1 + C45*n3*n1 + C64*n1*n2 + C24*n2*n2 + C44*n3*n2 + C63*n1*n3 + C23*n2*n3 + C43*n3*n3
    Tij[2,0] = C51*n1*n1 + C41*n2*n1 + C31*n3*n1 + C56*n1*n2 + C46*n2*n2 + C36*n3*n2 + C55*n1*n3 + C45*n2*n3 + C35*n3*n3
    Tij[2,1] = C56*n1*n1 + C46*n2*n1 + C36*n3*n1 + C52*n1*n2 + C42*n2*n2 + C32*n3*n2 + C54*n1*n3 + C44*n2*n3 + C34*n3*n3
    Tij[2,2] = C55*n1*n1 + C45*n2*n1 + C35*n3*n1 + C54*n1*n2 + C44*n2*n2 + C34*n3*n2 + C53*n1*n3 + C43*n2*n3 + C33*n3*n3
    Tij_trans = np.transpose(Tij)
    Tij_inv = np.linalg.inv(Tij)
    ## R and T defined as above.  Q needs to be new - and not remove the rv2. Thus, we introduce Qv for "Q to determine
    ## critical velocity"
    Qv = np.ndarray(shape=(3,3))
    Qv[0,0] = C11*m1*m1 + C61*m2*m1 + C51*m3*m1 + C16*m1*m2 + C66*m2*m2 + C56*m3*m2 + C15*m1*m3 + C65*m2*m3 + C55*m3*m3
    Qv[0,1] = C16*m1*m1 + C66*m2*m1 + C56*m3*m1 + C12*m1*m2 + C62*m2*m2 + C52*m3*m2 + C14*m1*m3 + C64*m2*m3 + C54*m3*m3
    Qv[0,2] = C15*m1*m1 + C65*m2*m1 + C55*m3*m1 + C14*m1*m2 + C64*m2*m2 + C54*m3*m2 + C13*m1*m3 + C63*m2*m3 + C53*m3*m3
    Qv[1,0] = C61*m1*m1 + C21*m2*m1 + C41*m3*m1 + C66*m1*m2 + C26*m2*m2 + C46*m3*m2 + C65*m1*m3 + C25*m2*m3 + C45*m3*m3
    Qv[1,1] = C66*m1*m1 + C26*m2*m1 + C46*m3*m1 + C62*m1*m2 + C22*m2*m2 + C42*m3*m2 + C64*m1*m3 + C24*m2*m3 + C44*m3*m3
    Qv[1,2] = C65*m1*m1 + C25*m2*m1 + C45*m3*m1 + C64*m1*m2 + C24*m2*m2 + C44*m3*m2 + C63*m1*m3 + C23*m2*m3 + C43*m3*m3
    Qv[2,0] = C51*m1*m1 + C41*m2*m1 + C31*m3*m1 + C56*m1*m2 + C46*m2*m2 + C36*m3*m2 + C55*m1*m3 + C45*m2*m3 + C35*m3*m3
    Qv[2,1] = C56*m1*m1 + C46*m2*m1 + C36*m3*m1 + C52*m1*m2 + C42*m2*m2 + C32*m3*m2 + C54*m1*m3 + C44*m2*m3 + C34*m3*m3
    Qv[2,2] = C55*m1*m1 + C45*m2*m1 + C35*m3*m1 + C54*m1*m2 + C44*m2*m2 + C34*m3*m2 + C53*m1*m3 + C43*m2*m3 + C33*m3*m3
    res = []
    res = spo.minimize_scalar(lambda x: ((min(eigvals(Qv * np.cos(np.radians(x)) * np.cos(np.radians(x)) + (Rij + Rij_trans) * np.cos(np.radians(x)) * np.sin(np.radians(x)) + Tij * np.sin(np.radians(x)) * np.sin(np.radians(x)))) / rho)**(0.5))*(1/(np.abs(np.cos(np.radians(x))))), bracket=(-90,0,90), method='Golden')
    vel_L = res.fun.real
    vel_L_int = int(vel_L)
    print('velocity limit')
    print(vel_L)
    print(vel_L_int)
    Det_B_try = 1

    Qij = np.zeros(shape=(3,3))
    Qij[0,1] = C16*m1*m1 + C66*m2*m1 + C56*m3*m1 + C12*m1*m2 + C62*m2*m2 + C52*m3*m2 + C14*m1*m3 + C64*m2*m3 + C54*m3*m3
    Qij[0,2] = C15*m1*m1 + C65*m2*m1 + C55*m3*m1 + C14*m1*m2 + C64*m2*m2 + C54*m3*m2 + C13*m1*m3 + C63*m2*m3 + C53*m3*m3
    Qij[1,0] = C61*m1*m1 + C21*m2*m1 + C41*m3*m1 + C66*m1*m2 + C26*m2*m2 + C46*m3*m2 + C65*m1*m3 + C25*m2*m3 + C45*m3*m3
    Qij[1,2] = C65*m1*m1 + C25*m2*m1 + C45*m3*m1 + C64*m1*m2 + C24*m2*m2 + C44*m3*m2 + C63*m1*m3 + C23*m2*m3 + C43*m3*m3
    Qij[2,0] = C51*m1*m1 + C41*m2*m1 + C31*m3*m1 + C56*m1*m2 + C46*m2*m2 + C36*m3*m2 + C55*m1*m3 + C45*m2*m3 + C35*m3*m3
    Qij[2,1] = C56*m1*m1 + C46*m2*m1 + C36*m3*m1 + C52*m1*m2 + C42*m2*m2 + C32*m3*m2 + C54*m1*m3 + C44*m2*m3 + C34*m3*m3

    for v in range(1, vel_L_int):
        # Calculate rho vel-squared
        rv2 = rho * v ** 2

        # CORRECT Q matrix calculations 
        Qij[0,0] = C11*m1*m1 + C61*m2*m1 + C51*m3*m1 + C16*m1*m2 + C66*m2*m2 + C56*m3*m2 + C15*m1*m3 + C65*m2*m3 + C55*m3*m3 - rv2
        Qij[1,1] = C66*m1*m1 + C26*m2*m1 + C46*m3*m1 + C62*m1*m2 + C22*m2*m2 + C42*m3*m2 + C64*m1*m3 + C24*m2*m3 + C44*m3*m3 - rv2
        Qij[2,2] = C55*m1*m1 + C45*m2*m1 + C35*m3*m1 + C54*m1*m2 + C44*m2*m2 + C34*m3*m2 + C53*m1*m3 + C43*m2*m3 + C33*m3*m3 - rv2
        Qij_trans = np.transpose(Qij)
        Qij_inv = np.linalg.inv(Qij)


        # Create a new Nik matrix
        TR_ik = -1*np.matmul(Tij_inv, Rij_trans)
        TI_ik = Tij_inv
        QRTR_ik = -Qij + np.matmul(np.matmul(Rij, Tij_inv), Rij_trans)
        RT_ik = -1*np.matmul(Rij, Tij_inv)

        # Nik Creation
        Nik_r1to3 = np.concatenate((TR_ik,TI_ik),axis=1)
        Nik_r4to6 = np.concatenate((QRTR_ik,RT_ik),axis=1)
        Nik_whole = np.concatenate((Nik_r1to3,Nik_r4to6))

        # Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors of Nik
        eigvals, eigvecs = eig(Nik_whole)

        ## The following code sorts the eigenvalues for those with negative imaginary numbers, and conducts the matrix
        ## operations to generate the B, A, and Z matrices from the COLUMNS in Pythons representation of eigenvectors
        eigvecsT = np.transpose(eigvecs)
        output_ab = output_ab_neg_imag = eigvecsT[eigvals.imag < 0]
        output_abT = np.transpose(output_ab)

        ### This is the B matrix (bottom 3 vectors assumed as b)
        B_matrix = output_b = np.delete(output_abT, [0,1,2], axis=0)
        B_matrixT = np.transpose(B_matrix)

        ### This is the A matrix (these are the displacement vectors, and when A is combined with B, the surface impedance (Z) matrix can be found)
        A_matrix = output_a = np.delete(output_abT, [3,4,5], axis=0)
        det_B = np.linalg.det(B_matrix)
        det_cc_B = det_B.conjugate()
        det_B_x_det_cc_B = det_B*det_cc_B
        v_real = v.real
        det_B_x_det_cc_B_real = det_B_x_det_cc_B.real

        if det_B_x_det_cc_B_real < Det_B_try:
            RSW_vel = v_real
            Det_B_try = det_B_x_det_cc_B_real
            
    print('RSW =')
    print(RSW_vel)
    print('Min |B|x|B|* =')
    print(Det_B_try)

    col_to_be_added2 = np.array([p1, P, p2, RSW_vel])
    RSW_matrix = np.column_stack((RSW_matrix,col_to_be_added2))

    print('RSW vel matrix is')
    print(RSW_matrix)
```

Comment: If your code isn't easily readable (lots of scrolling) you loose a lot of readers.  Only a few will want to reproduce the run.  It is also hard to read the lambda expression that requires horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Report the error correctly. **"'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable"**,  It's not the `lambda` itself, but something used with in it.  If you add some diagnostic prints you'll see that it runs one iteration just fine.  The error occurs on the next iteration, meaning that you have redefined some function!

Comment: Read - and post - the full traceback.  Bad error summaries don't help anyone.  I also recommend staying away from a big lambda.  Write this as a readable function.  It'll be easier to debug.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. The root issue was that I had imported the eigenvalue solver from scipy.linalg as eigvals while using eigvals as a variable name for an ndarray so once it looped over itself the `TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable` error would trigger as the eigvals function was overwritten with the `eigvals` array.